# how to replace space one by one using regex in java?

Tags: java, regex

```
String name = "B R ER";
String[] a = {"U","G"};
For(int i= 0 ; i < a.length ; i++)
{
String temp = name.replaceAll("\\s",a[i]);
name = temp;
}
```

//  But on result it shows BGRGER ... how to get result BURGER.

Comment: don't use a regex. Iterate through all the chars, and append the current char, or its replacement, to a StringBuilder. You just need to increment a counter each time you make a replacement to point a the next element in the array.

Comment: Its troubling how you would get that result. Fundamentally, it should be a 1 to 1 replacement, not a replace all. Find and replace only 1 per itteration of string a's characters.

Comment: @JBNizet: That comment should be an answer, and I'd vote that up :-)

Comment: @FabianSteeg: I was hoping the OP would try something on his own, but he seems to just look for a ready-made solution. I'll leave him with the ones suggested here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of `replaceAll` you can use `replaceFirst` to replace only the first occurrence of regex but in this case you can totally avoid regex and use String methods like `indexOf`, `substring` etc to manipulate the output.

**EDIT:** Code as per comments:

```
String name = "B R ER";
String[] a = {"U","G"};
for(int i= 0 ; i < a.length ; i++) {
    String temp = name.replaceFirst("\\s", a[i]);
    name = temp;
}
System.out.println(name); // BURGER
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
  String name = "B R ER";
  String temp = "";
  String[] a = {"U","G"};
  for (int i= 0 ; i < a.length ; i++) {
      temp = name.replaceFirst("\\s",a[i]);
      name = temp;
  }
  System.out.println(temp);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
String name = "B R ER";
String[] a = {"U","G"};
for(int i= 0 ; i < a.length ; i++)
{
    String temp = name.replaceFirst("\\s",a[i]);
    name = temp;
}
```